# Random sampling for a list of tuples

Tags: python

I have a list of 220 tuples created by "12 combination of 3". Is there a way in Python to sample from this list of tuples such that every sample I select comprises all the 12 elements in the set?

For example, if the set is [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l], the random selection should look like [(a,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,i), (j,k,l)]. I tried the following

```
for y in range(4): 
 for x in range(2):
        print(random.sample(list, 4))
```

but many samples do not have all the elements of the mother set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the time complexity is huge, with a small set of 12 items, I can safely guarantee that the code would run in less than a second or two.

In return, this code can provide you **pure and unbiased random**, and you can generate as many samples as you wish. The more samples you generate and the fewer items the original set has, the less time it would likely take your code to run.

```py
def generate(n, lst):
    if n < len(lst) // 3:
        print(f'"It is impossible to generate {n} samples."')
    else:
        while True:
            stack = None

            for _ in range(n):
                tup = np.random.choice(lst, size=3, replace=False)

                if stack is None:
                    stack = tup
                else:
                    stack = np.vstack((stack, tup))

            if len(np.unique(stack.flatten())) == len(lst):
                return list(tuple(i) for i in stack)
```

Basically, it generates `n` samples until the samples meet the condition.

---

### Results

Generating six samples with the code above gives the result.

```py
>>> lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
>>> generate(6, lst)

[(5, 0, 2), (8, 1, 4), (0, 4, 7), (10, 7, 2), (9, 11, 2), (3, 6, 1)]
```

Generating four samples gives the following result.

```py
>>> lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
>>> generate(4, lst)

[(7, 10, 11), (0, 4, 3), (1, 8, 5), (2, 9, 6)]
```

It is impossible to satisfy the condition with three samples.

```py
>>> lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
>>> generate(3, lst)

"It is impossible to generate 3 samples."
```

Comment: Thank you, Martes! However, your code generates "It is impossible to generate n samples." all the time. My list comprises 220 elements wherein each element is a triplet... [(a,b,c), (d,e,f), ...]. Is there anything I need to do?

Comment: @Nanda Your list should be flat, for example `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l]` instead of `[(a,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,i), (j,k,l)]`, in order for it to work. This code will do the combinations for you.

Comment: @Nanda Do you need any help?

Comment: Sorry, I still do not get the required combinations. The list is now flat as you suggested. Your code generate 10 samples (for n = 10) where each sample is a triplet such as (i, j, k), (a,c,d), etc.  

For instance, I need something like this: sample1 = [(a,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,i), (j,k,l)]. Essentially, every sample should have all the elements of the list. 

My apologies if I was not clearer in my question! I am not a software programmer, my Python background is very sketchy.

Comment: @Nanda Ok, I have updated my answer. To make it more clear, say I have a list of 12 `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l]`. If I generate 4 samples, it would work because 4 times 3 is 12. Or 5 samples, 5 times 3 is 15. 15 is greater than 12 so it would also work. But if I generate 3 samples, 3 times 3 is just 9. 9 is less than 12 so it is impossible to generate. If there is anything you don't understand, just feel free to ask me!

Comment: @ Mark -- sincere thanks Mark!  I will work on this and update you.

Comment: Perfect!  Worked exactly the way I wanted.  Many thanks!

Comment: The funny thing is that I no longer need the "combination" part of the code. I had used list(itertools.combinations('abcdefghijkl', 3)) for that purpose. Now, I can simply use the flat list as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

How about shuffling the original set/list and then take 3-tuples from that shuffled list?

```py
import random

lst = range(12) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

lst_shuffle = random.sample(lst, k=len(lst)) # shuffle the list
smp = [tuple(lst_shuffle[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(lst_shuffle), 3)] # make chunks
print(smp) # e.g., [(0, 2, 10), (3, 5, 4), (11, 7, 8), (1, 9, 6)]
```

I believe this is more memory-efficient while probabilistically equivalent.

Comment: Thank you! But I still do not understand how to generate 5 samples (say) using your code.  Is there a tweak that needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `random.shuffle` then use `zip` and `tuple` and get what you want:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(123)
>>> lst = list(range(12))
>>> random.shuffle(lst)
>>> lst
[7, 5, 9, 2, 3, 8, 11, 10, 6, 1, 4, 0]

>>> tuple(zip(lst[::3], lst[1::3], lst[2::3]))
((7, 5, 9), (2, 3, 8), (11, 10, 6), (1, 4, 0))
```